# Motoroloa barcode scanner beam width

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode-scanner, motorola

In my application, am using Motorola barcode scanner to scan barcodes. Here i have question, that is "Is it possible to reduce the width of the Beam that is sending from the barcode scanner?".

Please help me anybody, because everytime i have place the scanner very near to the barcode and needed to scane like this.

Give me some suggesstion to scan quickly.

Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide enough details in your question that could be answered specifically.  What model scanner are you using?  What are you trying to scan?

Generally, you cannot alter the physics or the optics of the reader.  There may be a setting that could provide different ways to improve read reliability, but they would be very model specific.

Are you trying to scan a printed barcode, or a cell phone barcode?  Some scanners have settings that change the illumination source making reading of cell phones more reliable.

My recommendation would be to ask your scanner vendor for their advice.  They may have a firmware upgrade that improves read reliability for your model.  Or perhaps you will need to purchase new scanners to achieve your speed goals.